# Child branch not animating with parent view

Tags: ios, animation, swiftui, transition, parent

I have the following custom action sheet with options (details omitted for simplicity):

```swift
var sheet: some View {
    VStack {
        HStack { /* some stuff here */ }
        
        list(of: options)
            .readSize($optionsSize)
            .wrappedInScrollView(when: optionsDontFit)
            .transition(.opacity)
    }
    .readSize($sheetSize)
}
```

where:

- `list(of:)` is just a `VStack` arranging all options' views
- `readSize(…)` is a modifier I created that updates a provided binding via a `GeometryReader`;
- `optionsDontFit` is a computed Bool property (depending on `sheetSize` and `optionsSize`);
- `wrappedInScrollView(when:)` is the following:

```swift
fileprivate extension View {
    @ViewBuilder
    func wrappedInScrollView(when condition: Bool) -> some View {
        if condition {
            ScrollView {
                self
            }
        } else {
            self
        }
    }
}
```

The problem arises when the parent of the sheet is animated e.g. via a transition from the bottom:

```swift
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        /* some stuff here */
        VStack {
            Spacer(minHeight: 42)
            if !isDismissed {
                sheet.transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
            }
        }
    }
    .onAppear { isDismissed = false }
}
```

The issue is that the sheet itself **does not slide with the parent**, but appears instead directly at the final position. The **closing** (dismissing) animation however **works as expected**.

**If I remove the scrollview wrapper func, eveything is fine.**

Here is a screen rec of the problem:

[image: preview]

Any idea what is going on?

I tried removing the scrollview wrapper func, and it animates correctly, but I have a requirement that the options list should be scrollable on smaller devices where the options take up the entire screen.

I tried moving the `transition` modifiers elsewhere but to no avail (also those should be the correct places).

I tried putting a `transition(edge: .bottom)` for the `list(of:)` as well but this will not work in some other scenarios with the full code I have (I actually have a `switch-case` over there that either presents a loader, or a list, so when state is changed while it is loading it reappears from the bottom of the screen while the parent is already moving further above).

Comment: If the ```ScrollView``` is causing the issue then you could maybe try the technique shown as answer to [How to keep the ScrollView height to the minimum necessary in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76641742), as replacement for your ```wrappedInScrollView``` approach.

Comment: @BenzyNeez I need to animate the change in height though, and also I don't always know in advance the size of the options and have a loading spinner there instead. 

By the way, about the problem described - I detected that it's because the `readSize` modifier uses a `Color.clear.onAppear` approach, a slight fraction of the second after things are on screen the value of `optionsDontFit` changes and produces a new tree without a scroll view, which has this problematic animation.