# How to keep the ScrollView height to the minimum necessary in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I need to create a card type view that is centered.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                .padding(.bottom)

            Text("Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text")
        }
        .padding(50)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .background(.black.opacity(0.2))
        .cornerRadius(50)
        .padding()
    }
}
```

The text within the card may be too long to fit on the screen, so I need to make the inside of the card scrollable.

Using `ScrollView` will make it scrollable, but the card will extend to its maximum height even if the text is short.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollView { // <-------- Add this
                Image(systemName: "globe")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                    .padding(.bottom)

                Text("Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text")
            }
        }
        .padding(50)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .background(.black.opacity(0.2))
        .cornerRadius(50)
        .padding()
    }
}
```

[image: Left side is the expected view, right side is the scrolling view added.]

Is it possible to give the card scrolling capability while keeping the height of the card to the minimum necessary?

The use of `Spacer()` was ineffective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Edited to hide the base view, instead of masking it out, as this works better.*

You can get close to what you are after by using an overlay to display the scrolled content:

- Establish the minimum space that is needed to display the text by showing this as the base view in hidden form. Even though the view is hidden, it still occupies layout space. The content will be truncated/clipped if it exceeds the height available.
- Overlay the same content as an overlay, nested inside a `ScrollView`. The overlay automatically adopts the size of the base view.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    private var backgroundColor: Color {
        Color(white: 0.8)
    }

    private var mainContent: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                .padding(.bottom)

            Text("Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text")
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        mainContent
            .hidden()
            .overlay {
                ScrollView { mainContent }
            }
            .padding(50)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .background(.black.opacity(0.2))
            .cornerRadius(50)
            .padding()
    }
}
```

The only small drawback is that even a small amount of text will behave as if scrollable (it will respond to drag gestures because it is inside a `ScrollView`).