# SwiftUI - Text alignment issues

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have created a custom header view and would like to place the text horizontally centered. However even with HStack and Spacer on the left and a button on the right, my text doesn't get horizontally centered. Adding code and expected screenshot and screenshot of how the output of my code looks.

***Code:***

```
private var headerView: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 0) {
        HStack {
            Spacer() // Tried replacing Spacer with Text(""), but then below scrollview width becomes very small.
            ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                VStack(spacing: 0) {
                    Text("PXL_458345883_54815348358")
                        .font(
                            Font.custom("SF Pro Text", size: 17)
                              .weight(.semibold)
                          )
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                    HStack(alignment: .center) {
                        Text("JPG Image").font(.subheadline).foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                        VStack(alignment: .center) {
                            Spacer()
                            Text(verbatim: "\u{002E}").font(.subheadline.bold()).foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                            Spacer()
                        }
                        Text("405 KB").font(.subheadline).foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                    }
                }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
            }
            
            Spacer()
            Button {
                // button action
            } label: {
                Text("Done").font(.body.bold())
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .trailing)
            .padding(.trailing, 20.0)
        }
        .padding(.top, 10.0)
        .padding(.bottom, 5.0)
    }
}
```

***Expected*** - Something like what's highlighted in purple except in my case file name is long, so I have wrapped in horizontal scroll and the file name should be centered aligned and not left aligned.

[image]

***Outcome of my code*** - Apart from text in center of the header view, I also want the "dot" between "JPG Image" and "405 KB" to be vertically centered.

[image]

***Output after trying @nickreps approach*** of adding GeometryReader. The text is now center for longer file names, but if the file name is smaller, then the text is left aligned. After wrapping VStack in GeometryReader, I tried `.frame(width: geometry.size.width * 0.62, alignment: .center)` and `.frame(width: geometry.size.width * 0.62)`

[image]
[image]

**Screenshot after trying Benzy's solution:**

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the `ScrollView` with the (possibly) long text in an overlay:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    private let theFilename = "PXL_458345883_54815348358"

    private var headerView: some View {
        HStack {
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                Text(theFilename)
                    .lineLimit(1)
                    .hidden()
                    .overlay {
                        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                            Text(theFilename)
                                .lineLimit(1)
                                .fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: true)
                        }
                    }
                    .font(
                        Font.custom("SF Pro Text", size: 17)
                            .weight(.semibold)
                    )
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                HStack {
                    Text("JPG Image").font(.subheadline)
                    Text(verbatim: "\u{002E}")
                        .font(.subheadline.bold())
                        .offset(y: -4)
                    Text("405 KB").font(.subheadline)
                }
                .foregroundColor(.gray)
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            Button {
                // button action
            } label: {
                Text("Done")
                    .font(.body.bold())
            }
        }
        .padding(.horizontal, 20.0)
        .padding(.top, 10.0)
        .padding(.bottom, 5.0)
    }

    var body: some View {
        headerView
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

More notes:

- This draws on the solution I gave as an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76644977/20386264) to the question "How to keep the ScrollView height to the minimum necessary in SwiftUI?".
- Suggest using a y-offset to make the dot vertically centered in the HStack on the second row.

---

*EDIT* Following up on your comment, here is the same example as you used in your screenshot, with shading to illustrate the padding and spacing being used:

[image: Shading]

- yellow shading is shown behind the filename
- green shading is shown behind the file info
- you can see, that the filename is exactly centered over the info
- blue shading is used to show the spacing for the HStack
- pink shading is used to show the padding around the HStack.

From this screenshot it should be clear, which padding or spacing you need to change if you want the VStack with the file details to be positioned diferently.

If, on the other hand, you want the dot to be centred, this can be achieved by applying `maxWidth: .infinity` to the file type and size:

```swift
    HStack {
        Text("JPG Image").font(.subheadline)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .trailing)
        Text(verbatim: "\u{002E}")
            .font(.subheadline.bold())
            .offset(y: -4)
        Text("405 KB").font(.subheadline)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
    }
```

This works nicely for a short filename, but it probably looks off-center for a longer one:

[image: CenteredDot2]

---

*EDIT2* Mixed layout

Perhaps the best solution is a mix of both approaches, choosing the centered-dot version when the filename is short. For example, if you had a computed property like this:

```swift
    private var isFilenameShort: Bool {
        theFilename.count < 10
    }
```

then you could use it for switching the layout:

```swift
    HStack {
        Text("JPG Image").font(.subheadline)
            .frame(maxWidth: isFilenameShort ? .infinity : nil, alignment: .trailing)
        Text(verbatim: "\u{002E}")
            .font(.subheadline.bold())
            .offset(y: -4)
        Text("405 KB").font(.subheadline)
            .frame(maxWidth: isFilenameShort ? .infinity : nil, alignment: .leading)
    }
```

[image: MixedLayout]

Comment: Your solution is close to what I need. Works great with longer string, but if the string size is smaller, then it's still towards left. Last screenshot in my question shows how it looks with smaller string.

Comment: Glad to hear its close, but don't quite understand what you mean by "still towards left". Looking at your image, PXL is almost exactly centred to the info on the bottom line (I make it 172 pixels from the start of the J of JPG to the start of the P of PXL and 170 pixels from the end of the L of PXL to the end of the B of KB). The other spacing is controlled by the HStack spacing and the horizontal padding - trivial to change these. So I wonder if you are looking to have the dot in the middle and the filename centred over the dot? This of course means, a long name would look off-center.

Comment: Answer updated as follow-up.

Comment: Thanks Benzy for explaining in detail! When you look at it from user's point of view (attached one more screenshot - same as other screenshot, but in full view), the file name and file description are exactly horizontally centered within HStack. I am trying to fix that. But since your answer is closure to what I need, I will go with it.

Comment: Really loved the idea of adding ScrollView overlay on file name Text. Would have never thought about it.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're seeing is due to the HStack splitting the two views within it equally. You need to specify a frame on the `ScrollView` of a specific size to make sure it has priority for that space inside the HStack.

Below I've integrated an example with `GeometryReader` that sets the frame size of the scrollview to 80% of the `HStack` width. You can modify the value as needed.

```
private var headerView: some View {
    GeometryReader { geometry in // Added geometry reader here
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            HStack {
                Spacer() // Tried replacing Spacer with Text(""), but then below scrollview width becomes very small.
                ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                    VStack(spacing: 0) {
                        Text("PXL_458345883_54815348358")
                            .font(
                                Font.custom("SF Pro Text", size: 17)
                                    .weight(.semibold)
                            )
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                        HStack(alignment: .center) {
                            Text("JPG Image").font(.subheadline).foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                            VStack(alignment: .center) {
                                Spacer()
                                Text(verbatim: "\u{002E}").font(.subheadline.bold()).foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                                Spacer()
                            }
                            Text("405 KB").font(.subheadline).foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                        }
                    }
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
                    
                }
                .frame(width: geometry.size.width * 0.8) // <--- here!!
                Button {
                    // button action
                } label: {
                    Text("Done").font(.body.bold())
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .trailing)
                .padding(.trailing, 20.0)
            }
            .padding(.top, 10.0)
            .padding(.bottom, 5.0)
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This worked partially. If the file name is little smaller then it left aligns more than being in the center. I will update my question with the screenshots of this approach.

Comment: Glad to hear. I was working with the limited code provided. It would be difficult to provide a perfect example without the remaining code. If line wrap is needed, or other features are needed, that would necessitate a separate question.

If this answers the question, please be sure to mark it as accepted!