# How to start the overlay after last Text from the view in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, ios16, swiftui-zstack

I have a `ScrollView` with some text in it and I want to use `.overlay` for an `Image` to start after last `Text` or element from the view.

In a simple way I used `Color` to showcase what I have and what I want to achieve.

Using `offset` would shift the view down with a fixed amount. I assume that with `GeometryReader` that `offset` could be dinamically?

But that would cover the `tabBar` as shown in this example.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
        
            ScrollView {
                VStack {
                    Text("Text 1")
                        .font(.title)
                    Text("Text 2")
                }
                VStack {
                    Text("Text 3")
                    Text("Text4")
                }
                .padding()
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .overlay(
                ZStack {
                    Color.red
                        .offset(y: 100)
                        .opacity(0.5)
                }
            )
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "house.circle")
                Text("Home")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

I tried with `alignment` on `overlay`, `ZStack` or on `ScrollView` but no success. Some of the alignment modifiers I tried are `trailingLastTextBaseline` or `leadingLastTextBaseline`.

Is there a way for the `overlay` to start right after `Text 4` and not cover the `tabBar`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want the `ScrollView` to use the minimum height necessary and then the remaining space should be filled with the image. If this is correct, then the solution from [How to keep the ScrollView height to the minimum necessary in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76641742/20386264) can be used. This means moving the `ScrollView` to the overlay, the image just follows in the regular layout.

If there is a lot of text then the image might need to be allowed to consume a minimum height, this is done by applying `.frame(minHeight)`.

Hope this works as you were wanting:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    private var textContent: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Text 1")
                .font(.title)
            Text("Text 2")
//            Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.")
//                .font(.title)
            Text("Text 3")
                .padding(.top, 50)
            Text("Text4")
        }
        .padding()
    }

    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                textContent
                    .layoutPriority(1)
                    .hidden()
                    .overlay(alignment: .top) {
                        ScrollView {
                            textContent
                        }
                    }
                Color.red
                    .frame(minHeight: 100)
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "house.circle")
                Text("Home")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: RemainingSpace]

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to answer my question. The answer provides what I needed in terms of `.overlay` starting right after last element from `ScrollView`, just need some tweaks for my need.