# How to make ScrollView shrink to fit and take minimum space without hacks

Tags: swift, swiftui

In SwiftUI, a ScrollView will take all the available space. But I need to position two ScrollViews in a VStack so that they take the space respectively (see below).
Here is an image of what I want to code:

[image: ScrollView adjustments]

This image shows three different states:

1. Two ScrollViews with minimal content take minimal space;
2. ScrollView #1 is long and takes more space, but ScrollView #2 is shown fully;
3. Both ScrollViews are long and take 50% of the screen each.

After searching everywhere and playing with the code, I've found 1.5 ways to achieve this:

One approach is: https://github.com/onmyway133/blog/issues/769 And it involves placing a Color.clear on the background and reading it's size with GeometryReader. Then updating the `@State` variable. Hovewer this method doesn't account for screen rotation. So it won't do.

The second way utilizes **PreferenceKey**. We, again, add a `Color.clear` background to the content of ScrollView, read it's size with GeometryReader, pass it and change it via a PreferenceKey.

Question: Are we certain that this is the way to do it? That looks like the mother of all hacks! Not to mention a potential performance hit.

Here is my Opt.2 code to checkout if you want to dive in:

```
@main
struct ThatApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ScrollsView()
        }
    }
}

struct ScrollViewHeightPreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: CGFloat = .zero
    static func reduce(value: inout CGFloat, nextValue: () -> CGFloat) {
        value += nextValue()
    }
    
    typealias Value = CGFloat
}

struct ScrollsView: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            ShrinkingScrollView(title: "First Scroll View", isLong: false)
            ShrinkingScrollView(title: "Second Scroll View", isLong: false)
        }
        .frame(width: 300)
        .background(Color.blue.opacity(0.3))
        .padding() // just for beauty
    }
}

struct ShrinkingScrollView: View {
    let title: String
    let isLong: Bool
    
    //This will be the height of the ScrollView:
    @State private var height: CGFloat = .zero
    
    
    //Not important text string
    let string = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text(title)
                .fontWeight(.bold)
            
            ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: true) {
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
                    Text(string)
                    if isLong {
                        Text(string)
                        Text(string)
                        Text(string)
                    }
                }
                .background {
                    GeometryReader { geo in
                        Color.clear
                            .preference(key: ScrollViewHeightPreferenceKey.self, value: geo.size.height)
                    }
                }
            }
            .onPreferenceChange(ScrollViewHeightPreferenceKey.self) {
                height = $0
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: height)
            .scrollBounceBehavior(.basedOnSize, axes: .vertical) //We are > iOS 16.4
            .border(Color.red, width: 3)
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ScrollsView()
}
```

Comment: You could try to use a [custom layout](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/10056/)

Comment: Can you clarify what it means for a view to be "long"? How long is "long"?

Comment: @Sweeper sorry for that. I meant the text is lengthy enough to exceed the screen size and require the user to scroll to see the full content.

Comment: Perhaps something could be done with [`ViewThatFits`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/viewthatfits)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the technique described in the answer to [How to keep the ScrollView height to the minimum necessary in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76644977/20386264)

- The main content of each scrolled view is shown at its natural size, without nesting it in a `ScrollView`, but hidden.
- The visible version is then shown as an overlay, nested in a `ScrollView`.

Like this:

```swift
struct ShrinkingScrollView: View {
    let title: String
    let isLong: Bool

    //Not important text string
    let string = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

    private var mainContent: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
            Text(string)
            if isLong {
                Text(string)
                Text(string)
                Text(string)
            }
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text(title)
                .fontWeight(.bold)
            mainContent
                .hidden()
                .overlay {
                    ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: true) {
                        mainContent
                    }
                    .scrollBounceBehavior(.basedOnSize, axes: .vertical) //We are > iOS 16.4
                }
        }
        .border(Color.red, width: 3)
    }
}
```

The parent view `ScrollsView` is unchanged, the preference key `ScrollViewHeightPreferenceKey` is not needed any more.

---

*EDIT* The answer from *sweeper* got me thinking. I was surprised that `ScrollView` delivers a useful ideal size, it doesn't just grab all the space available. However, if you try to use `fixedSize()` to force it to adopt the ideal size, it doesn't work when the height is greater than the screen height. So what is needed, is a custom `Layout` that sets the height to `min(idealHeight, availableHeight)`. After that, `VStack`can be used to share the space in the usual way.

So here is another (perhaps slightly less hacky) solution that uses this approach. First the custom `Layout`, which is only expecting to have one subview:

```swift
struct OptimalHeight: Layout {

    public func sizeThatFits(
        proposal: ProposedViewSize,
        subviews: Subviews,
        cache: inout ()
    ) -> CGSize {
        let result: CGSize
        if let firstSubview = subviews.first {
            let containerWidth = proposal.width ?? .infinity
            let containerHeight = proposal.height ?? .infinity
            let size = firstSubview.sizeThatFits(.init(width: containerWidth, height: nil))
            result = CGSize(width: containerWidth, height: min(size.height, containerHeight))
        } else {
            result = .zero
        }
        return result
    }

    public func placeSubviews(
        in bounds: CGRect,
        proposal: ProposedViewSize,
        subviews: Subviews,
        cache: inout ()
    ) {
        if let firstSubview = subviews.first {
            firstSubview.place(
                at: CGPoint(x: bounds.minX, y: bounds.minY),
                proposal: .init(width: bounds.width, height: bounds.height)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

This can be used inside the `body` of `ShrinkingScrollView` as follows:

```swift
var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        Text(title)
            .fontWeight(.bold)
        OptimalHeight {
            ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: true) {
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
                    Text(string)
                    if isLong {
                        Text(string)
                        Text(string)
                        Text(string)
                    }
                }
            }
            .scrollBounceBehavior(.basedOnSize, axes: .vertical) //We are > iOS 16.4
        }
    }
    .border(Color.red, width: 3)
}
```

As before, the parent view `ScrollsView` is unchanged, the preference key `ScrollViewHeightPreferenceKey` is not needed any more.

Comment: I like your approach. It's still hacky, but so elegant and straightforward, doesn't involve calculations, and works on iOS < 16!

Comment: @Anna Answer updated with a second possible approach that uses a custom Layout (inspired by *sweeper*'s answer).

Answer (score 3):

As one of the comments suggests, this can be done with a custom `Layout`.

In `placeSubviews`, you should get the ideal sizes (i.e. content sizes) for each scroll view, and determine which of the 3 cases it is.

Here is an example.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    public var body: some View {
        MyLayout() {
            // change the numbers 100 and 10 to see the different cases
            ScrollView {
                ForEach(0..<100) { _ in
                    Text("Long Text 1")
                }
            }
            
            ScrollView {
                ForEach(0..<10) { _ in
                    Text("Long Text 2")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct MyLayout: Layout {
    // this will be used when the proposal does not specify a height
    let idealHeight: CGFloat = 500

    // returns the size of the whole layout, given the size of the available space
    func sizeThatFits(proposal: ProposedViewSize, subviews: Subviews, cache: inout ()) -> CGSize {
        assert(subviews.count == 2)
        
        let idealSize1 = subviews[0].sizeThatFits(.init(width: proposal.width, height: nil))
        let idealSize2 = subviews[1].sizeThatFits(.init(width: proposal.width, height: nil))
        let layoutHeight = min(proposal.height ?? idealHeight, idealSize1.height + idealSize2.height)
        return CGSize(width: max(idealSize1.width, idealSize2.width), height: layoutHeight)
    }
    
    func placeSubviews(in bounds: CGRect, proposal: ProposedViewSize, subviews: Subviews, cache: inout ()) {
        assert(subviews.count == 2)
        let idealSize1 = subviews[0].sizeThatFits(.init(width: proposal.width, height: nil))
        let idealSize2 = subviews[1].sizeThatFits(.init(width: proposal.width, height: nil))
        let layoutHeight = bounds.height

        // here we determine which case it is.
        if idealSize1.height + idealSize2.height > layoutHeight {
            if idealSize2.height < layoutHeight {
                // case 2: 
                // second view short, first view long
                // place the second view at the bottom with its ideal height
                // let the first view fill the rest of the space
                subviews[0].place(
                    at: CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.minY + (layoutHeight - idealSize2.height) / 2),
                    anchor: .center,
                    proposal: .init(width: idealSize1.width, height: layoutHeight - idealSize2.height)
                )
                subviews[1].place(
                    at: CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.maxY - idealSize2.height / 2),
                    anchor: .center,
                    proposal: .init(width: idealSize2.width, height: idealSize2.height)
                )
            } else {
                // case 3:
                // both views long, let both views fill the space equally
                subviews[0].place(
                    at: CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.minY + layoutHeight / 4),
                    anchor: .center,
                    proposal: .init(width: idealSize1.width, height: layoutHeight / 2)
                )
                subviews[1].place(
                    at: CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY + layoutHeight / 4),
                    anchor: .center,
                    proposal: .init(width: idealSize2.width, height: layoutHeight / 2)
                )
            }
        } else {
            // case 1:
            // both views short
            subviews[0].place(
                at: CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.minY + idealSize1.height / 2),
                anchor: .center,
                proposal: .init(width: idealSize1.width, height: idealSize1.height)
            )
            subviews[1].place(
                at: CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.maxY - idealSize2.height / 2),
                anchor: .center,
                proposal: .init(width: idealSize2.width, height: idealSize2.height)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

You can expand this by adding some spacing and other cases if you'd like.

Comment: It's interesting that a `ScrollView` delivers a useful ideal size that depends on the content, it doesn't just consume all available space automatically. If only there would be a way to have `HStack` and `VStack` base their layout on the ideal size of the subviews, instead of their max size, then a lot of workarounds could be avoided.

Comment: I created a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77635838/20386264) to explore this further.

Comment: This answer got me thinking and I updated my own answer with another way of using a custom `Layout` (I gave yours an upvote in thanks!).