# How to use ideal size for HStack and VStack layout, instead of max size

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-layout

`HStack` and `Vstack` usually base their layout on the maximum size of the subviews. Here is an example:

```swift
HStack {
    Color.orange
        .frame(idealWidth: 200, maxWidth: .infinity)
    Color.purple
        .frame(idealWidth: 100, maxWidth: .infinity)
}
.padding()
.frame(height: 100)
```

[image: MaxWidth]

However, when the same `HStack` is nested inside a `ScrollView`, the ideal size is used instead:

```swift
ScrollView(.horizontal) {
    HStack {
        Color.orange
            .frame(idealWidth: 200, maxWidth: .infinity)
        Color.purple
            .frame(idealWidth: 100, maxWidth: .infinity)
    }
}
.padding()
.frame(height: 100)
```

[image: IdealWidth]

So I'm wondering, is there a way to have an `HStack` or `VStack` base their layout on the ideal size, instead of the max size, without nesting inside a `ScrollView`?

One solution might be, if the subviews could be wrapped in some way so that they return their ideal size as the max size. Any suggestions on how to do this?

Of course, a custom `Layout` could be built to do the job. But can it be done without going this route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
.fixedSize()
```

> Fixes this view at its ideal size.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/fixedsize()